# Chrome devtools - Панель Elements, при обновлении ajax'ом выделенный элемент изменяется. Как сделать чтобы не менялся?

Tags: google-chrome

Как избавиться от такого поведения? Спасибо. Нужно чтобы какой выделили элемент такой и оставался выделенным

Answer (score 1):

Панель Elements специально разработана для отображения страницы в реальном времени. В самом браузере текущей версии опции отключения такого поведения нет, такого флага запуска браузера не встречал.

Как варианты выхода из ситуации:

1. Использовать отладочные точки в коде для вывода элемента в консоль.
2. Использовать [API командной строки](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api) для вывода элемента в консоль до и после обновления. Например, для этого ответа на вопрос меняется время с момента ответа (не ajax, но логика понятна):
   [image: Изменение времени ответа на этот вопрос]
   для переключателя сайтов в левом верхнем углу этого сайта до и после нажатия:
   [image: До и после нажатия на переключатель]
3. Другие интересные методы отладки [в документации](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#setting-dom-breakpoints) и [популярно](http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/246557/).